# Is changing sharepoint registry values supported?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server

we are required to add the attribute '`Encrypt=true`' in connection string for enabling SSL connection to SQL DB.

Can we change this in connection string through registry settings under this location?

RUN -> REGEDIT and surf to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure\ConfigDb`

Is this supported from Microsoft?

Answer (score 2):

In common any changes per Regedit are not supported.
Therefore Microsoft published this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316898/how-to-enable-ssl-encryption-for-an-instance-of-sql-server-by-using-mi it should be supported.

Answer (score 2):

On SharePoint Server changing the registry key is unsupported, unless any Official Microsoft KB Article mention it or you open a Microsoft Support ticket and they told you to do it.

There are many examples where Official KB article or Technet told to change the key. So it is upto you which process / steps you are following.